# Почему «Ни в сите, ни в решете»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, литература

Существует такая поговорка:

> **Ни в сите, ни в решете**
> *Петерб.* Посредственно, ни хорошо, ни плохо.
> *[Большой словарь русских поговорок. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина.]*

Почему «ни в сите, ни в решете» значит посредственно?

Согласно [Википедии](http://%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%CC%81,%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5.):

> **Си́то** — инструмент для просеивания более мелких материалов (сыпучих масс: зёрен, круп, песка и тому подобное), по величине их частиц.
> …
> Также используется разновидность сита — **решето́**, в котором размеры отверстия сетки более крупные.

Таким образом, решето крупнее чем обычное сито.

Получается, что что-то не проходит ни через более мелкие отверстия обычного сита, ни через более крупные отверстия решета. Или что-то не остаётся ни в сите, ни в решете при просеивании.

На чём основана аналогия? Что такое сеяли, что решили сравнить это с посредственностью?

---

Интересное использование обратного этой поговорке выражения есть в романе «Отцы и дети» И. С. Тургенева:

> — Ты действительно изменился в это последнее время, — заметил Аркадий.
>  — Ничего! поправимся. Одно скучно — мать у меня такая сердобольная:
> коли брюха не отрастил да не ешь десять раз на день, она и убивается.
> Ну, отец ничего, тот сам был везде, **и в сите и в решете.**

Что значит, был и в сите и в решете? Сильно худел, так что проходил через маленькие отверстия, раз речь до этого идёт про то что «брюхо не отрастил». Или прошёл через испытания, которые его потрепали? Но почему именно сито и решето?

Тургенев, по всей видимости, взял за основу поговорку и «ни в сите, ни в решете» и переделал с противоположным смыслом. Было «ни в сите, ни в решете», а стало «и в сите, и в решете»

И ещё почему у Тургенева И. С. не стоит запятая: «...и в сите и в решете».

Comment: Для просеивания (проживания)? //// Очевидно, раздельного.

Comment: @shampar Мне ваша мысль не понятна.

Comment: Вы привели статью с непонятной для меня целью: эти предметы широко известные в быту и по литературе. В статье оказалось случайное в этом ряду слово — проживание. В других источниках в череде действий с решетом (наряду с просеиванием) стоит процеживание.

Comment: @shampar Что значит «Очевидно, раздельного»?

Comment: @shampar Вы шутить изволите? Пожалуйста, не отнимает время такими вещами.

Comment: @shampar Возьмите за правило не отнимать время глупыми шутками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут особой проблемы нет.
Сито и решето – два инструмента (ну или предмета кухонной утвари), которые используются для разных продуктов или материалов. К примеру – муки и зерна. К тому же у сита и решета в обшем-то разное назначение. Как правило (не всегда), через сито просеивают мелкий ингредиент, мусор остается на решетке. А в решете – наоборот, мелкий мусор отсеивается, проникая через отверстия.

Естественно, что проходит в сито, то пройдет и в решето. Но смысла использовать решето там, где нужно сито, нет никакого. Нужна "специализация".
А материал, который не пригоден к обработке ни ситом, ни решетом, вроде как и получается чем-то посредственным.

Что до Тургенева, то я не вижу причин связывать представленный эпитет с худобой.
Просто герой был вездесущ, мог оказаться и "в сите" и "в решете".

А насчет запятой. Тут, конечно, больше догадки, чем объективное понимание. Но все-таки, похоже, запятая там не нужна, поскольку (предположительно) это фразеологизм, не Тургеневым придуманный, но к нашему времени прочно забытый.

Как вариант – автор углядел тесное смысловое единство (наподобие "и день и ночь", "и туда и сюда"). В этих случаях запятая тоже не ставится. Последнюю версию отчасти подтверждает связь с поговоркой, ибо, как правило, такое смысловое единство строится на явном противопоставлении, а в поговорке это противопоставление хорошо выражено.

Comment: Насчёт запятой вы, вероятно, правы. Я проголосовал за ваш ответ. Но по ситу и решету надо ещё подумать, может кто-то что-то ещё скажет.

Comment: Исходя из ответа вашего ответа, можно сделать вывод, что в сите просеивают что-то мелкое, отделяя его от более крупных включений, а в решете просевают что-то крупное, отделяя его от мелких примесей.

Если что-то будет среднего размера, то оно не пройдёт через сито, но и не останется в решете. Таким образом, оба инструмента будут не применимы.

Из этого можно сделать заключение, что «ни в сите, ни в решете» — это «ни маленький и ни большой», средний, к которому не применимо ни сито, ни решето.

Answer (score 1):

В [словаре Даля](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F_(2-%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_4_(1882).pdf/104) есть только вариант с *ни* («Живется — ни въ сито, ни въ решето!»), напоминающий многочисленные вариации на тему «ни то ни сё»: *ни рыба ни мясо, ни два ни полтора, ни в тын ни в ворота, ни Богу свечка ни чёрту кочерга, ни украсть ни покараулить...* :) Возможно, это искажение (либо шуточная переделка) изначального варианта с *и*: как я уже писал, на мысль о его изначальности наводит рифма.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, что второй ответ Егора Салькова остался незамеченным, мне он кажется верным.

**О значении пословицы**

Сравним:  Живется –  ни в сито, ни в решето. В.И.Даль. Пословицы... Жизнь моя в Петербурге ни то ни се (А.С. Пушкин).

Очевидно, что содержание двух фраз совпадает, так что нет ничего загадочного в сите и решете – это просто образное выражение того же местоименного сочетания **«ни то ни се».**  Ну а «ни сите ни в решете» – это «ни так ни сяк».

**Фразеологизмы-синонимы:** ни рыба ни мясо; серединка на половинку; ни богу свечка ни черту кочерга; ни два ни полтора; ни пава ни ворона; ни пришей ни пристегни.

Другой вариант – **и так и сяк**, то есть по-всякому: Старший умный был детина, средний сын и так и сяк, младший вовсе был дурак».

Вот и у Тургенева Базаров переиначил пословицу на свой лад (если можно так сказать, подошел творчески):  Ну, отец ничего, тот сам был везде, и в сите и в решете (во всяких ситуациях).

**Почему у Тургенева нет запятой?**

Чем более распространенным является фразеологизм, тем сложнее произнести его в одну фразу, обозначив смысловое единство однородных членов – соответственно, запятая в этих случаях ставится: ни в сито, ни в решето, но: ни то ни се.

Также многое зависит и от структуры самого предложения, где используется фразеологическое сочетание. Так, в предложении  у Тургенева  (при наличии **пояснительной** конструкции) удобнее слитное произношение: Ну, отец ничего, тот сам был вездЕ, и в сите и в решетЕ.

Comment: Он не остался незамеченным, я за него проголосовал и его прокомментировал. Кто-то поставил минус, поэтому там ноль. У Behemothus, на мой взгляд, хорошие мысли и развёрнутый ответ. Я принял его ответ. Принять несколько ответов не могу. По части запятой ответ Егора повторяет мысль Behemothus другими словами. Насчёт рифмы — я согласен, но думаю, что переносный смысл сита и решета также имеет место. Вам тоже спасибо за ответ, я за него проголосовал.

Comment: Рифма тут ни при чем, а сито и решето – это всего лишь ОБРАЗ, его можно заменить любым другим, хоть самим придумать: ни в сито, ни в решето – значит, ни туда ни сюда.  Но местоименная форма не так выразительна, как реальное сравнение. Вот эту мысль высказал Егор, а об этом никто не сказал (вот что меня удивило).  Кроме того, сочетание можно перефразировать на утвердительное, что и сделал Базаров. (Минус, возможно, поставили за первый ответ, а я говорю про второй.) Я ставлю голос за ваш вопрос – он интересен тем, что раскрывает две актуальные темы (фразеологию и  запятые в сочетании И…И).

Comment: Запятые вообще не объяснили, как я думаю. Это довольно сложный вопрос,  и в каждом случае свое решение (общего нет). (Даже у Розенталя  говорится о том, что запятая при наличии союзов И…И и тесном единстве  ОБЫЧНО не ставится.) Постановка запятой  зависит как  от распространенности самого сочетания,  так и от предложения, где оно применяется (нужно учитывать структуру и интонацию). У Тургенева запятая связана с пояснительной конструкцией  (вездЕ, и в сите и в решетЕ).

Answer (score 0):

Поговоркам нередко свойственна рифма; скорее всего, и эта поговорка изначально звучала в рифму: «Был везде — и в сите, и в решете». Сито и решето — символы испытаний и отбора: крупное решето — менее строгого, мелкое сито — более. А запятой у Тургенева здесь нет потому, что в его время это был устойчивый фразеологизм.

Comment: Я думаю, что Тургенев, скорей всего, использовал, это выражение не в противоположном поговорке смысле, а, действительно, как метафору испытаний. Имеется ввиду: прошёл через большие и маленькие жизненные испытания.
Я принял ответ behemothus, как более ранний и содержащий хороший мысли, но за оба ваших ответа я тоже проголосовал, чтоб вы получили баллы. У вас тоже есть хорошие мысли.